# How to make only the .text of a div clickable to trigger an event?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I have some DIVs with an eventListener for clicks. For design reasons, these DIVs have margins assigned with CSS and some have line breaks. However, somehow the area around the words is also clickable and triggers the event (of the nearest word) -- what I don't want. So how can I prevent anything but the shown text of the DIV itself to be clickable, e.g. "trends"?

```
    <div id="wordbox">
        <div id="ai"><h2>artificial intelligence</h2></div>
        <div id="tr"><h4>trends</h4><br><br></div>
        <div id="dm"><h3>data mining</h3></div>
    </div>
```

```
  var wb = document.querySelectorAll("#wordbox > div");
  Array.from(wb).forEach(function(element, index) {
      element.addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert(element.id);
      });
  });
```

```
#ai{
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    margin-right: 1.0%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same idea, but changing the css a little bit

```js
var wb = document.querySelectorAll("#wordbox > div");
Array.from(wb).forEach(function (element, index) {
  element.children[0].addEventListener("click", function () {
  alert(element.id);
 });
});
```

```css
#ai{
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    margin-right: 1.0%;
} 

/* Make the texts not occupying the whole width */
#wordbox h2,
#wordbox h3,
#wordbox h4 {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="wordbox">
 <div id="ai"><h2>artificial intelligence</h2></div>
 <div id="tr"><h4>trends</h4><br /><br /></div>
 <div id="dm"><h3>data mining</h3></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `div > *` totally destroys my layout. This is my wordbox: `#wordbox {
 visibility: block;
 background: transparent;
 position: absolute;
 align-self: center;
 height: 440px;
 min-width: 500px;
 max-width: 1650px;
 align-items: left;
  justify-content: left;
}` But you seem to be right: Some words are taking too much width and expand the clickable area even over line breaks. Is there anything else I can do about that?

Comment: @Rome How about the new update? It just needs to be specific and only affects the header tags.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the click event to `div` which takes its own space so if you want to add click event to the inside text element then you should use `element.children[0]` like,

```
  element.children[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert(element.id);
  });
```

And snippet as follows,

```js
var wb = document.querySelectorAll("#wordbox > div");
  Array.from(wb).forEach(function(element, index) {
      element.children[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert(element.id);
      });
  });
```

```css
#ai{
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    margin-right: 1.0%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wordbox">
 <div id="ai"><h2>artificial intelligence</h2></div>
 <div id="tr"><h4>trends</h4><br><br></div>
 <div id="dm"><h3>data mining</h3></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hm, I tried your code but it does not change anything, there are still areas around the words clickable. children[0] makes perfect sense though. Can there be anything else causing this effect?

Comment: @Rome, Do you want click on the text element alone eg.., ```trends``` or in ```<h4> trends </h4>```? It is now working on ```<h4> trends </h4>``` as per my solution..

Comment: The text alone.

Comment: @Rome, You can use event listener only on the HTML element, If you don't bother in changing the ```CSS``` then use the css changes mentioned in another solution.

Comment: @Rome, If there is possibility to modify your ```HTML``` then you can use like this, https://codepen.io/manmur/pen/GRRzPmL

Comment: Here there is no need of css changes but you can achieve with Javascript itself..

Comment: The above CSS solution finally did it for me. I am using it with your `children[0]` approach, thank you!

Comment: @Rome, No probs , You can accept any solution that solves your issue, but if you need to complete the scenario entirely in javascript then you can look at this solution, https://codepen.io/manmur/pen/GRRzPmL  here I have made your js code to work in ES6 version which is latest..

Answer (score 0):

I'd first replace the divs with spans. A div will always take the width of the container element. Without arbitrarily shrinking the div, using spans is much more succinct. Then slightly modify you event listener function and it should work fine.

```
<div id="wordbox">
    <h2><span id="ai">artificial intelligence</span></h2>
    <h4><span id="tr">trends</span></h4><br><br>
    <h3><span id="dm">data mining</span></h3></a>
</div>

var wb = document.querySelectorAll("span");
wb.forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener("click", function() {
      alert("clicked!!!");
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried your approach but `span` brings back the clickable areas around the words and using `children[0]` with `div` is straight forward imho. Your changes to the EventListener are a good simplification though.